# custom control style with x:Shared and EventSetter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can make the following style for a ListView work as a user control (or window):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush
                x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                x:Shared="False"
                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" />
            <SolidColorBrush
                x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}"
                x:Shared="False"
                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColorKey}}" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <EventSetter
            Event="MouseLeftButtonUp"
            Handler="ListView_Content_MouseLeftButtonUpEvent" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

How can I get the same result in a custom control?
I need the "x:Shared" so that the color is re-calculated when the system colors change.
I need the EventSetter for some special handling.  However, neither of these are supported in Generic.xaml.  What is the correct way to get these features in a custom control?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the Style.Resources in the Generic.xaml so I do not understand what might be wrong there.

To attach an event handler override the OnApplyTemplate of the custom control and add the event handler in code.