# Using EventSetters in Custom-Control to add MouseDoubleClick to a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control that is supposed to auto-complete stuff. For this, a Popup is getting created where the user can pick the wanted item.

This all works perfectly fine already, with a tiny problem: I want those items (presented inside of a `ListView`) to also auto-complete using a double click.

This however, presents a problem to me as i cannot add an EventSetter onto the style for the corresponding `ListViewItem`.

I want to avoid having to add a dependency property with some ICommand to relay the whole thing via attached properties.

XAML code (broken down):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:AutoCompleteTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoCompleteTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoCompleteTextBox}">
                <!-- ... -->
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ...}" IsOpen="{Binding ...}">
                    <ListView ItemTemplate="{Binding ...}" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <!-- 'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the MouseDoubleClick event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root element. -->
                                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </Popup>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: So where are you defining the event handler? And what are you doing in it?

Comment: nowhere currently @mm8 as it is not possible like it is done above. I want to have it inside of my `AutoCompleteTextBox` Control. The Style is inside the `Themes.xaml`. In the end, the double click is supposed to auto-complete (aka replace) the `Text` field of the control.

Comment: In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729335/custom-control-style-with-xshared-and-eventsetter) is the following suggestion: **To attach an event handler override the OnApplyTemplate of the custom control and add the event handler in code.** Does that help?

Comment: @PhilJollans theoretically you are right but practically it is not possible due the targeted items being potentially not existing at `OnApplyTemplate` calltime. It is about `ListViewItem` afterall :/